# Easy way to change SVN URL in a large collection of TeamCity VCS roots at once?

Tags: teamcity

Does anyone know of a way to change the SVN url on a large number of VCS roots at once?  Our SVN server is changing it's base URL and there's way too many VCS roots to change manually through the TC interface.

We are using SQL Server as the database for TeamCity so I'm going to poke around the schema.  Doesn't seem like it will be a good idea tho.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All current VCS settings in TeamCity are stored in the file vcs-roots.xml in [TeamCity configuration](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD6/TeamCity+Data+Directory) directory. So you can shutdown the server, make the change, and start the server again.
(Actually, you can make the change without shutdown phase, TeamCity should pick the changes on the fly)

Don't forget to backup the file first.

Comment: Odd.  I didn't think this data directory was used if you were using SQL Server instead of the internal db.  It looks like the database holds the history of changes to the VCS roots but the XML holds the current state.

Comment: Exactly. Previous states are stored in DB, current ones - in XML.

Comment: Note in TeamCity 8.0 the VCS settings were moved into the project xml files ([TW-8576](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-8576)).